# Deleted user's posts showing in 'First Posts' queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, deleted-accounts

On Scifi.SE, a user had their account deleted this morning.  Also this morning, about half a dozen of "their" posts were in the First Posts queue.  The posts were all roughly a month old, and they all had the same disassociated user#.  [Here's](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/7949) one of them.

Why'd this person's posts show up in the First Posts queue?  Why do a deleted user's posts *ever* show up in that queue, when it's purpose is to help the community provide feedback to new users?  A deleted user is no longer a member of the community, and they're not even going to be able to act on any feedback.

Comment: Yeah, this is a bug. There's no check for a null owner, and since deleted posts aren't associated with any user there are never any "previous" posts with the same author... Kinda surprised this hasn't been caught before now!

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272135/first-posts-escape-review-when-user-self-deletes-account) is an answer to "Why do a deleted user's posts *ever* show up in that queue" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.

Afterwards un-owned posts will never enter the First Posts queue, and any posts in the queues will be removed.