# First posts escape review when new user self-deletes account

Tags: bug, review, new-users, deleted-accounts

For example, see [this post](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2480/advice-ms-in-mathematics-to-increase-competitiveness-for-phd-programs/60825#60825) on Academia (deleted now.) It's clearly intended to be a comment, but was posted as an answer. The content of the post is:

> +1 to @ff524♦'s comment-I know that you have never heard of a university with an age limit on funding,you requested me to not post comments as answers as if I register my account (instead of deleting it),then I'll be able to comment on my own posts myself,but what I said about the stopping of the OP's fellowship is that if he cann't finsh his PhD before attaining the age of 35 years then he will never be able to complete it (trivial answer to be converted into comment to ff524♦'s post)

A new user account posted this, and it was pushed into the first posts review queue. Then the user deleted his own account (but not the post). A few minutes later, the [review job](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/31937) is invalidated. The post is removed from the review queue without ever being reviewed, and escapes notice until 9 hours later.

The [stated purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) of the First Posts queue

> is to give special attention to users who may need to be educated on some aspect of our model **and to posts that are more likely to need improvement**.

(emphasis mine.)

Why should a potentially problematic post be removed from review, just because the person who posted it deleted his account? The post may still need attention.

Comment: Sounds just fine for me. What is the bug exactly? What you expect to happen?

Comment: @ShadowWizard why should a potentially problematic post be removed from review, just because the person who posted it deleted his account? The post may still need attention.

Comment: Because the reverse [was reported as a bug 2.5 years ago, and fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170445/deleted-users-posts-showing-in-first-posts-queue). (Sounds like weird version of ping pong to me ;))

Comment: @Sha This bug addressed another problem. The problem was, if any user deletes the account (*it's not necessary for them to be new*), the posts of them go to the review queue. This addresses  the problem about *actually new* user deleting their account, though I'm afraid there couldn't be a check if the user was new or not...

Comment: @nicael hmm... still not sure I understand this, but anyway better that what the OP said in the previous comment be added into the question itself

Comment: @ShadowWizard nice find. What nicael said is part of the bug reported there (that *all* of a deleted users' posts are pushed to first posts queue.) And I guess my post is the answer to the other part: "Why do a deleted user's posts ever show up in that queue"

Comment: FWIW, @Sha we have a competent troll on Chem who posts an answer to bountied questions and then deletes their account. Chem is a relatively small site, so it's easy to find and deal with their post, but I don't think that's possible on bigger sites.

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. that user is the subject of this post. He does that thing with the bountied questions network-wide (and engages in other disruptive behaviors as well, always with the common thread of creating a new account and then deleting it after posting.)

Comment: Oh interesting.

Comment: So in that case a CM is needed to put a network wide suspension, IP based. This way troll is trapped with one suspended account and can't delete it anymore. /cc @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ.

Comment: This has become slightly less of a problem recently due to changes with how user account deletion is handled: now, all users who've posted on the site in the past have to wait 24 hours for their deletion request to be processed, whereas at the time this was posted, users who've made only one post got to have their deletion processed immediately without a wait.