# First posts escape review when user deletes and undeletes post

Tags: bug, review, new-users, deleted-posts

Similar to [First posts escape review when new user self-deletes account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272135/295232), it seems to be possible to avoid your first post from being reviewed simply by deleting it, waiting a few minutes (until the review item becomes invalidated) and undeleting it. This happened [here](https://stackapps.com/posts/8866/timeline) – there doesn't seem to be any malicious intent there, but a clever spammer might be able to exploit it.

[image]

Comment: *A clever spammer* ... show one ;)

Comment: One example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66314075/timeline) as well I think. The question it self is subpar but it needed some monitoring by chatroom regulars to notice the undeletion.

Comment: status-by-design I guess?