# When does a first post review get invalidated?

Tags: support, review

I recently noticed [this](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/1150943) review. It was [invalidated](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1345436/timeline#review_1150943) and I could not understand the reason for invalidation.

After a bit of searching in Meta Stack Exchange, I found [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190581) in which it was mentioned:

> If the review task is removed due to other circumstances outside the queue (e.g. a moderator deletes a post that is being reviewed, outside the queue), it is marked "invalidated" or "no longer reviewable".

But in this case, a moderator did not delete the post.

Even [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361253) is not relevant as the OP did not delete and undelete their post.

So, why was the review invalidated?

Comment: 14 days between creation of the task and its invalidation. I suspect an automatic process.

Comment: @rene Can you please share the source of information?

Comment: On SO a lot of those can be found: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1455788

Comment: The source of my information is my gut feeling.

Comment: The [timeline](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1345436/timeline#review_1150943) shows two timestamps with 14 days between next to the FP queue entry, though those aren't labeled...

Comment: @rene is right, see the second last paragraph of Shog9's answer in the linked question.

Comment: @Rob I don't think that is the case.

Comment: @rene is indeed right. Posts more than 14 days old were not eligible for the first posts queue.